# Nim game backtracking doesn't work on all row sequences - Java

Tags: java, backtracking

I have a question. As an assignment we have to make the Nim game resolver using backtracking to predict which player is going to win based on the input on which player is going to start first (assuming that both players have a perfect decision rate).

Here is the code for the NimGame:

```
package Nim;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NimGame {

private int[] elements;

public NimGame(int[] elements) {
    this.elements = new int[elements.length];
    this.elements = elements;
}

public int NimSolver(boolean player) {
    if (player == true && NimHelp(elements) == true) {
        return 1;
    } else if (player == false && NimHelp(elements) == true) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        int score = 0;
        int tmp = 0;

        if (player == true) {
            score = -1;
        } else {
            score = 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 1; j <= elements[i]; j++) {
                // Decrement element (Do thing)
                elements[i] -= j;

                // Backtrack
                tmp = NimSolver(!player);

                // SetScore
                if (player == true && tmp > score) {
                    score = tmp;
                } else if (player == false && tmp < score) {
                    score = tmp;
                }

                // Increment element (Undo thing)
                elements[i] += j;
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
}

private boolean NimHelp(int[] elements) {
    boolean[] isEmpty = new boolean[elements.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i] == 0) {
            isEmpty[i] = true;
        } else {
            isEmpty[i] = false;
        }
    }

    for (boolean value : isEmpty) {
        // If not all value is empty return false
        if (!value)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void NimResult(int player,int result)
{
    if (player == 1) {
        result = NimSolver(true);
    } else if (player == 2) {
        result = NimSolver(false);
    }

    if (result == 1) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("PLAYER 1 WON");
    } else {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("PLAYER 2 WON");
    }
}

public void NimPrint(ArrayList<Integer> element)
{   
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("MATCHES--------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < element.size() ;i++)
    { 
        System.out.println("");
        for (int j = 0; j < element.get(i) ; j++) {
        System.out.print("|");
        }
    }

} 
}
```

Here is the code for Test Main class:

```
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import Nim.NimGame;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows;
    int elementTmp;

    ArrayList<Integer> rowTmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int playerNo;
    int result = 0;
    int[] elements;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input number of rows: ");
    rows = sc.nextInt();

    elements = new int[rows];
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Input number of elements in each row");

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        System.out.print("Row number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        elementTmp = sc.nextInt();

        elements[i] = elementTmp;
        rowTmp.add(elementTmp);
    }

    NimGame nim = new NimGame(elements);


    nim.NimPrint(rowTmp);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("First player to move");
    System.out.println("1) Player 1");
    System.out.println("2) Player 2");
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    playerNo = sc.nextInt();

    nim.NimResult(playerNo, result);
}

}
```

It works for the sequence: 3 rows , Row1 = 1, Row2 = 2, Row3 = 3 for example:

```
Input number of rows: 3

Input number of elements in each row
Row number 1 : 1
Row number 2 : 2
Row number 3 : 3

MATCHES--------------------------------------
|
||
|||
---------------------------------------------

First player to move
1) Player 1
2) Player 2
Input: 1

PLAYER 2 WON
```

But it doesn't work for all the sequences. I don't understand why.